# Ошибка - Cannot read properties of null (reading 'value')

Tags: javascript, type-error

**Столкнулся с ошибкой**

[image]

Сам код -

```
<script>
mult = function() {
    var second = document.getElementById('usdt1').value;
    document.getElementById('result').value = 42 * second;
    var second2 = document.getElementById('btc2').value;
    document.getElementById('result').value = 12000 * second2;
    var second3 = document.getElementById('eth3').value;
    document.getElementById('result').value = 120 * second3;
    var second4 = document.getElementById('ltc4').value;
    document.getElementById('result').value = 50 * second4;
    var second5 = document.getElementById('busd5').value;
    document.getElementById('result').value = 43 * second5;
    var second6 = document.getElementById('usdc6').value;
    document.getElementById('result').value = 44 * second6;
    var second7 = document.getElementById('dash7').value;
    document.getElementById('result').value = 746 * second7;
}
</script>
```

Помогите пожалуйста решить, мучаюсь очень долго.

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! [как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: На момент запуска вашей функции, в DOM нет одного из элементов, которые вы отбираете `getElementById`. Либо рано запустили скрипт, либо ошиблись с ID

Comment: Либо ошиблись с идентификатором, либо вставили и вызвали JavaScript код перед добавлением соответствующих html-элементов. В любом случае из ошибки понятно что вы не можете по id  найти какой то из элементов

Answer (score 1):

В приведённом ниже примере скрипт с атрибутом **defer** будет ожидать, когда все элементы DOM будут загружены, соответственно, если ошибки в id-элемента ошибки не будет, вы получите необходимое значение.

```js
<head>
<script defer>
  var mult = function() {
    var second = document.getElementById('usdt1').value;
    document.getElementById('result').value = 42 * second;
    var second2 = document.getElementById('btc2').value;
    ....
  } 
</script> 
</head> 
<body>
  <input id="usdt1" type='text'></input>
  <input id="usdt2" type='text'></input>
</body>
```

Также, вы можете поместить скрипт в самый низ body, уже после создания всего дерева DOM.